# Difference between <a> and <button>

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

I recently modified a bit of a button to give it a 3d effect in a **bootstrap** site.

The result satisfied me, but when I applied the style to tag `<button>` instead of `<a>` I had several problems.

You can find the code in question here: http://jsfiddle.net/wctGM/3/

I hope someone can help me, because I can not in any way to move forward

Comment: Hi Marco. If you want HTML tags (or other code) to show up in your questions, try wrapping them in backticks (the visual editor will do this for you if you highlight them and press the "code" ({}) button.) I've done this for you for this question

Answer (score 2):

You must use `border: none`:

```
button {
    border: none;
    margin-top : 50px;
}
```

Your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/wctGM/7/

Answer (score 1):

There are some things which are different to each other. For an instance if you set the `border:none;` property for a button you will get rid of that border. But the width and height remains different. What I mean to say is go through the default properties which are set on each html tag and try to understand them and then try to change.

See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wctGM/5/). I have added border property like below.

```
button {
    margin-top : 50px;
    border:none;
}
```